# Dubai (UAE) flights connection without leaving the airport

Tags: visas, transit, airport-transfer, dubai, uae

I have the following flights bought as separate tickets from different companies:

Manila (Philippines) - Dubai (UAE) = Cebu Pacific Airlines

Dubai - Russia = Ural Airlines

both arrival and departure will be in same Terminal 1 in Dubai Int Airport.
I will have 14 hours between flights.

I have Russian passport, thus I'm not allowed to exit transit zone without visa.
Here are my questions:

1. How should I check-in myself and my luggage for the next flight in Dubai without leaving the transfer zone?
2. May I have any problems during boarding in Manila?

Comment: There are transfer desks for all airlines in the transit area. no worries. check this: http://www.dubaiairports.ae/before-you-fly/procedures/flight-connections

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some investigation I got the answers.

1. UAE allows transit without visa when the time between connecting flights is less than 24 hours.
2. You can not receive and check-in your luggage yourself in Dubai without getting out of the transit terminal. But there is a special service for such cases - Marhaba Service. You don't need to preorder anything - when you come to Dubai you just need to find them there and they will help you. Cost - 300 AED per person (about +80USD currently).
3. Cebu Pacific which operates my flight from Manila knows all the above and even allows to purchase Marhaba Service right before the boarding in Manila airport for reduced price - only 160 AED. If you don't have UAE visa but have purchased Marhaba Service then you will be allowed to fly. 
   *Upd. they have purchased me 2499 php (~200 aed).*

Comment: Great information!